# Http and scope not getting data from mongodb

Tags: angularjs, mongodb

I want to retrieve the data from users inside my admin mongdb, I followed the instructions here https://plnkr.co/edit/em7Xv1XtzDumYQGg2Fbo?p=preview for creating paginated tables but why `http.get` doesn't get the values from mongodb? Am I missing something. Please help me I'm solving this for hours and tried every solution.

```
angular.module('mainController', ['ui.bootstrap'])

.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.userData = [];
    $scope.pageSize = 3;
    $scope.currentPage = 1;
    $http.get('/users').then(function(data){
        $scope.userData = data.data.users;
        console.log(data);
    })
})
```

Comment: You'll need to show your backend implementation of the `/users` action to get any useful help here.

Comment: It doesn't seems to be **$http.get** issue, probably a issue with your action. Please check your action code...

Comment: try to test your backend with postman, putting your url.. and see what it resolves